# Understanding how nested routes work in react-router

Tags: webpack, react-router, nested-routes

I am really struggling to understand how nested routes work with react-route.
I have looked at many similar questions but I can't get things to work.

My goal is to have child components displayed **inside** their parent component and accessed accordingly with the corresponding url `/parent/child`.

I have this configuration:

```
<Router history={browserHistory}>

   <Router path="/" component={App}>

       <IndexRedirect to="/welcome" />

       <Route path="/welcome" component={WelcomePage} />

       <Route path="/services" component={ServiceView}>
            <Route path="new" component={AddServiceView} />
       </Route> 

   </Router>
</Router>
```

So I enter this url `"/"` in the browser, the `WelcomePage` (nested withing the App component) is correctly displayed.
When I enter `"/services"`, the ServiceView is correctly displayed (nested inside the App view). Here is a simplified layout of the ServiceView component:

```
<div>
     <Header>
        Services
     </Header>    
     {this.props.children}   
     <Footer />       
</div>
```

Now this is where I'm having my problem. When I enter this url `"/services/new"`, I would expected the `AddServiceView` be displayed nested within its parent component where there is the `{this.props.children}`. Instead I get a blank page in my browser.

If in my routing configuration above, I change the path for `AddServiceView` from `path="new"` to `path="/new"`(notice the slash) and I hit this url `"/new"`, then
`AddServiceView` is correctly displayed, nested within its parent.

This confuses me. This url `/new` tends to indicate that the view displayed is located at the root of the application.

So my question is: why am I not able to display a child component nested within its parent through a nested url `/parent/child` (this follows the Routes layout), instead I am accessing this child component through this misleading url `/child`?

I hope that my question is clear. Thank you for your suggestions.

**Notes**: I am using using vscode + webpack + react + typescript. In some posts some people suggested there might be a problem with webpack and the way it works with react-router. But since I am new to webpack, I am not able to investigate their solution in my case.

Comment: I had a look at the chrome debug console and for this url "/services/new", there is a 404 ( not found) error: bundle.js  So it looks like the error is related to webpack...Is my assumption correct?

Answer (score 0):

For any one trying to have react-router nested routes work with webpack dev server, this [github post](https://github.com/luqin/react-router-loader/issues/15) gives the answer: basically use absolute paths in your index.html when you reference your .js files. For example use `/bundle.js` instead of `bundle.js`